# how can i connect my usb port to ATmega16

Tags: calculator

I have a calculator circuit and i want to  be connected to pc with a USB port,this circuit contains a ATmega16 micro,my question is how can i see dats that keypad sends in both calculator lcd an pc lcd with this micro.

Answer (score 1):

as jippie said, it's not clear what you are asking exactly.
But from the title, I'm assuming that you need to interface PC with ATmega16 right.

jippie had give a good option. But another alternative is vusb.

take a look at vusb support page for your ATmega16 : http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to understand, but I think you are looking for a 'USB to serial converter'. You can make the ATmega output serial data through its UART and send it to the converter. The converter attaches to the PC as a standard `COMn` on Windows or `/dev/ttyUSBnn` in Linux. They come in many variations and at various prices. You shouldn't have to pay more than couple of $$ for it.

Here is an [example](http://dx.com/p/pl2303hx-converter-usb-to-ttl-usb-to-com-cable-module-black-1m-150928).

Comment: I've pay around 7$.BTW just for curiosity.